# GCC 7 not choosing the correct type trait specialization

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, type-traits

I am having some issues with gcc 7.2. I have this type trait

```
template<typename T>
struct audio_frame_channels {}

template<int N>
struct audio_frame_channels<std::array<float, N>> {
  static constexpr auto value = N;
};
```

And then i use it like this:

```
  template<typename T>
  auto redirect(T& buf) ->
  ProcessData<audio_frame_channels<std::remove_reference_t<
                                     decltype(buf[0])>>::value>;
```

clang 6 has no issue with this, but gcc 7.2 complains that `‘value’ is not a member of ‘top1::audio::audio_frame_channels<std::array<float, 1> >’`
Have i gotten something wrong, or is this what you get on experimental compilers?

Edit: Obligatory godbolting:

https://godbolt.org/g/Y1EFYC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second template parameter for `std::array` is a `std::size_t`, not `int`. You need to change it like so:

```
template<std::size_t N> //instead of int N
struct audio_frame_channels<std::array<float, N>> {
  static constexpr auto value = N;
};
```